# Вопрос по двунаправленному итератору

Tags: c++, list, struct, итераторы

Вообщем выполняя лабораторную работу столкнулся с проблемой ввода и удаления структур из STL list , так как итераторы совершенно не хотят принимать инкрементацию или декрементацию(Expression : cannot increment end list iterator)...Не могу понять в чём причина , если итератор поставить в начало списка и ставлять элементы через Students.insert , проблем не возникает... Вот сам код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

#undef max
using namespace std;
struct students 
{
    int  year;
    long long int telephon;
    wstring lastname;
    wstring name; 

};

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int year, x;
    int n;
    unsigned int position;
    long long int telephon;
    wstring lastname;
    wstring name;
    list<students> Students;
    auto it = Students.begin();
    students *tmp = new students;
    do
    {
        wcout << L"1. Добавить элемент" << endl;
        wcout << L"2. Удалить элемент" << endl;
        wcout << L"3. Вывести список" << endl;
        wcout << L"0. Выйти" << endl;
        wcout << L"\nНомер операции > ";
        while (!(cin >> x) || (cin.peek() != '\n'))
        {
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
            wcout << L"Ошибка ввода,повторите ввод: ";
        }
        switch (x)
        {
        case 1:


            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            wcout << L"Имя > "; getline(wcin, name);
            wcout << L"Фамилия > "; getline(wcin, lastname);
            wcout << L"Год рождения > ";
            while (!(cin >> year) || (cin.peek() != '\n'))
            {
                cin.clear();
                while (cin.get() != '\n');
                wcout << L"Ошибка ввода,повторите ввод: ";
            }
            wcout << L"Телефон > ";
            while (!(cin >> telephon) || (cin.peek() != '\n'))
            {
                cin.clear();
                while (cin.get() != '\n');
                wcout << L"Ошибка ввода,повторите ввод: ";
            }

            wcout << L"Позиция > "; cin >> position;

            tmp->year = year;
            tmp->telephon = telephon;
            tmp->name = name;
            tmp->lastname = lastname;
            it++;
            Students.insert(it, *tmp); 
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:  
            if (Students.empty()) { wcout << L"\nСписок пустой...\n\n"; }
            else for (it = Students.begin(); it != Students.end(); ++it) {
                wcout << L"\n{ " << it->name << L" ";
                wcout << it->lastname << L" ";
                wcout << it->year << L" ";
                wcout << it->telephon << L" }";
                cout << "\n\n";
            }
            break;
        }
    } while (x != 0);
}
```

P.S Хочу разобраться , подтолкните хотя бы в нужную сторону...

Comment: "cannot increment end list iterator" означает что программа не может увеличить итератор, который указывает на конец списка. Куда вы его дальше собрались увеличить? Там дальше ничего нет.

Comment: Ой , это я игрался , так даже с begin() ничего не выходит...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас изначально итератор `it` установлен на начало *пустого* списка. То есть он равен `begin()` и `end()` этого списка одновременно. Затем вы для него делаете `it++`. Разумеется, это некорректная операция. Нельзя инкрементировать итератор `end()`.

Пока список пуст, не имеет значения, проинициализируете ли вы этот итератор значением `begin()` или `end()` - эти значения в пустом списке одинаковы.

---

Зачем вы вообще делаете это `it++`? Вам, как я понял, надо добавить элемент в конец списка. Тогда это просто

```
Students.insert(it, *tmp);
```

при этом `it` остается равным `end()` и не инвалидируется. Но зачем вообще нужен этот `it`, если можно

```
Students.emplace_back(*tmp);
```

???

И зачем `*tmp` размещается в динамической памяти?

Comment: А каким образом можно добавлять элементы , если нужную позицию указывает пользователь или как обезопасить от некоректного ввода?

Comment: Потому что нужно вводить структуру в место которое укажет пользователь при вводе position , как я понимаю делать это необходимо с использованием итераторов...Или есть ещё способы?*

Comment: @Logvas Channel: О, замечательно. Но что-то я не вижу у вас никаких попыток работы с этим `position`.

Comment: Просто если я пробую через advance(it , position) , то он выходит за пределы списка как писалось выше и выходит ошибка...

Comment: @Logvas Channel: Ну так а что за позицию вы передаете в `advance`??? Какая может быть позиция в **пустом** списке? Отвечаю: в пустом списке может быть только одна позиция - нулевая, `0`. Если вы передадите в `advance` что-то другое,то разумеется ничего работать не будет.

Comment: Ладно , спасибо вам ,подтолкнули в нужную сторону...Отмечаю как лучший ответ , приятного вечера(у меня так) и всего доброго ^_^